# web3: are event/filter results guaranteed to be sorted by block number?

Tags: web3js, events

I see that the results of past events which I get via

```
MyContract.MyEvent({}, { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' }).get((error, results) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

are sorted by block number. Can I rely on this ordering or is it possibly random? Chain re-organizations or forks are exceptions that I do not care about for now.

Is the behavior for `.watch` and `filter.watch` the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm one of [parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity) client developers and I can assure you that the ordering is defined (both in parity an geth) and you can safely rely on it. I see that it is not mentioned in the docs, so they need to be updated.

> Is the behavior for .watch and filter.watch the same?

Unfortunately I can't answer this question.

PS. If you are curious how event filters work, the implementation is available [here](https://github.com/paritytech/bloomchain)

Comment: Can anybody confirm this for `.watch` or `filter.watch` for geth?